# Fill radio button with data coming from database Laravel Blade

Tags: php, forms, laravel, radio-button, laravel-blade

So I am now working with the update part of my program, now i want to populate my forms with the older records from my database to edit it. Now my problem is the radio button, how can select the true one. I tried this code, i use if on my radio buttons

```
    {{ Form::label('Type','Type')}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    {{ Form::radio('ctype', '1',if(($item->bname)==1){true}) }}
    {{ Form::label('Rooster','Rooster')}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    {{ Form::radio('ctype', '0') }}
    {{ Form::label('Hen','Hen')}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

But I just get error 500, please help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the documentation it says:

```
echo Form::radio('name', 'value', true);
```

So you should go this way:

```
{{ Form::radio('ctype', '1', $item->bname == 1) }}
```

You shouldn't need any additional brackets. Third param is a simple boolean value.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I just dont know what is the '==1' for

Comment: you need the third param to either be true or false. In this case if your $item->bname value is 1 the radio will be checked (because 1 compared to 1 is true). Otherwise it will not be checked.

Comment: Basically you'll get a radio with a name "ctype" and value "1" which is checked if $item->bname is equal to 1

Comment: I just doublechecked - it is working. Probably the problem is with your $item or bname value. Check those. I just tried these: {{ Form::radio('ctype', '1', 1 == 1) }} and {{ Form::radio('ctype', '1', 0 == 1) }}, I got a checked and then unchecked radio with correct name and value.

Comment: I dont know how it workes on you sir, but i hard coded the variable sir, but it still doesnt work

Comment: Do you get any error message? Does it output anything? Does blade work at all? Do you get other form fields successfully? what do you get when calling <?php var_dump($item->bname); ?> ?

Comment: My fault sir, bname is not the boolean field I need, rooster_hen is the correct name of the field. Thanks!!!!!